# How can I get the directory that contains the executable in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Depending on the generator used, [`CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html) may or may not contain the executable. Using the Unix Makefiles generator, the executable is placed directly into this directory. However, using the Xcode generator, the executable is placed in a subdirectory (Debug or Release).

I'm trying to copy some files into directory next to the executable. This is what I'm doing but it only works when I use `make`. Maybe there's a better way?

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET Game POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets
)
```

I found [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html#variable:CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_%3CCONFIG%3E) but it doesn't seem to set. I tried `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` and the target properties `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` but they aren't set. Maybe this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the target directory associated with an executable target named `name_of_executable_target`, consider using the `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:name_of_executable_target>` generator expression.

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET Game POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:name_of_executable_target>/assets
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:name_of_executable_target>/assets
    )
```

For more details, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html